# Update Key credentials of Databricks Datasource on Power Bi, using power bi REST APIs

Tags: powerbi, databricks, powerbi-rest-api

I want to update Key credentials of Databricks Datasource on Power Bi, using power REST APIs.

I have created service principal on AAD, added it to security group, enabled it for power bi workspace.

Have used [Take Over](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/take-over-in-group) API of power bi, to get ownership of dataset.

But I am getting "PowerBINotAuthorizedException" error when I try [Update Gateway Datasource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/gateways/update-datasource) API.

Please help!